# Equivalence statement for existence product of modules

Tags: modules, infinite-product, universal-property

The following exercise is taken from T.S. Blyth book, Module Theory, chapter 6, exercise 9:

[image]

Something does not add up, especially with using (1). It seems that condition (1) is not necessary or sufficient here and the statement can be proved solely by (2).

This is because the $R$-morphism
$h:M\rightarrow\prod_{i\in I}M_i$ which can be defined by $h(x):=(\pi_i(x))_{i\in I}$ is exactly an Isomorphism if and only if (2) holds. And $h$ is an Isomorphism if and only if $(M,(\pi_i(x))_{i\in I})$ is a product of the family $(M_i)_{i\in I}$. Am I missing  something? I checked and re-checked over and over and I don't see why I need (1).

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez what do you mean? There cannot be more because it says unique

Comment: My dream is that I wake up in the morning and I see an answer here

Comment: @user264745 Thanks for your response. $\times_{j\in I} M_j$ is indeed a product of $R$-modules. I think regarding (2) he means a specific element in the product, so for each $j\in I$, we have ${x_j}$ some element in $M_j$.

Comment: @user264745 Well, it seems that this Exercise has condition (1) redundant. Because it seems to me that the statement is equivalent only to condition (2). This is my main concern there and the thing I am trying to figure out.

Comment: @user264745 thanks for the tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Definition:** [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory#Categories) is definition of category.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category and $\{X_j\mid j\in I\}$ be family of object of $\mathcal{C}$. A **product** for the family $\{X_j\mid j\in I\}$ is an object $X$ of $\mathcal{C}$ together with a family of morphisms $\{ \pi_j : X\to X_j \mid j\in I\}$ such that for any object $Y$ and family of morphisms $\{\varphi_j:Y\to X_j\mid j\in I\}$, there is a unique morphism $\varphi : Y\to X$ such that $\pi_j\circ \varphi =\varphi_j$ for all $j\in I$.

Product of family $\{X_j\mid j\in I\}$ is unique, in a sense, if $(P,\{\pi_j\})$ and $(Q,\{\psi_j\})$ are both products of the family $\{X_j\mid j\in I\}$ of objects of a category $\mathcal{C}$, then $P$ and $Q$ are equivalent.

---

**Proof:** Let $\mathcal{C}$ be category of $R$-modules. $(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $(M,\{\pi_j\})$ is product of family $\{M_j\mid j\in I\}$. Let $\prod_{j\in I}M_j$ be cartesian product of possibly infinite family $\{M_j\mid j\in I\}$, and let $\pi_j’: \prod M_j \to M_j$ be canonical projection for all $j\in I$. Then $(\prod M_j, \{\pi_j’\})$ is product of family $\{M_j\mid j\in I\}$ is quite a standard result. So $M$ and $\prod M_j$ are equivalent ($R$-module isomorphic).

Let $M\cong \prod M_j$ under an isomorphism $f:M\to \prod M_j$. Then $\pi_j=\pi_j’f$ by the definition of product. Let $i_j’:M_j\to \prod M_j$ be canonical injection. For all $j\in I$, define $i_j:=f^{-1}i_j’:M_j\to M$. So
$$\pi_k\circ i_j=\pi_k’f\circ f^{-1}i_j’=\pi_k’\circ i_j’= \begin{cases} \text{id}_{M_j}  & \text{if $k=j$} \\
0 & \text{if $k\neq j$}\end{cases}.$$
Condition $(1)$ satisfy. Since $f$ is equivalence (bijective), for every $(x_j)_{j\in I}\in \prod M_j$ there exists unique $x\in M$ such that $f(x)=(x_j)_{j\in I}$. So $$\pi_j(x)=\pi_j’\circ f(x)=\pi_j’((x_j)_{j\in I})=x_j.$$
Condition $(2)$ satisfy. Thus $\Rightarrow$ holds.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose family $\{i_j:M_j\to M\mid j\in I\}$ of morphism ($R$-module homomorphism) satisfies condition $(1)$ and $(2)$. We want to show $(M,\{\pi_j\})$ is product of family $\{M_j\mid j\in I\}$. Let $A$ be an object in $\mathcal{C}$ and family of morphism $\{\varphi_j:A\to M_j\mid j\in I\}$. Let $a\in A$. Then $(\varphi_j(a))_{j\in I}\in \prod M_j$. By condition $(2)$, $\exists !x_a\in M$ such that $\pi_j(x_a)=\varphi_j (a)$ for all $j\in I$.

Define $\varphi : A\to M$ given by $\varphi (a)=x_a$. Note $\varphi$ is a well defined function. So
$$\pi_j\circ \varphi (a)=\pi_j (x_a)=\varphi_j(a).$$
Thus $\pi_j\circ \varphi (a)= \varphi_j(a)$ for all $a\in A$. Therefore $\pi_j\circ \varphi = \varphi_j$ for all $j\in J$. Let $\psi :A\to M$ such that $\pi_j\circ \psi =\varphi_j$ for all $j\in I$. Fix $a\in A$. Then $\pi_j(\psi (a))=\varphi_j (a)\in M_j$. By uniqueness of $x_a$, we have $\psi (a)=x_a=\varphi (a)$. So $\varphi = \psi$. Thus $\exists !\varphi :A\to M$ such that $\pi_j\circ \varphi =\varphi_j$ for all $j\in I$. Hence $(M,\{\pi_j\})$ is product of $\{M_j\mid j\in I\}$. In proof of $\Leftarrow$ we didn’t make use of condition $(1)$.

**TL;DR** You were correct in your assessment of condition $(1)$ is not needed in the exercise.

Comment: exactly! no use of condition (1)

Comment: It is not uncommon for author to add extra condition in problem. Hypothesis doesn’t have to be as restrictive as possible. I guess, author wanted reader to prove specific property of product [condition $(1)$] without making it to another exercise.